# How to round up value in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a value like this:

```
$value = 2.3333333333;
```

and I want to round up this value into like this:

```
$value = 2.35;
```

I already tried round, ceil and etc but the result is not what I expected.

Please anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: Might I ask why you would want to round it up to 2.35? What's the criterion? Nearest 0.05?

Comment: @AlexGittemeier - no, it's not working, it returns 2.33

Comment: look at some of the code snippets from users here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php. Note that OP wants rounding **up**, not to the nearest 100th.

Comment: @Alex Gittemeier - +1, indeed, always read (and clarify if necessary) the spec.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking your question literally, this will do it:

```
$value = (round($original_value / 0.05, 0)) * 0.05
```

i.e. will round to the *nearest* 0.05.

If, for some reason, you want to *always round up* to 0.05, use

```
$value = (round(($original_value + 0.025) / 0.05, 0)) * 0.05
```

Comment: this work well, but can you make it available to this range 2.11111111111111 up to 2.15, 2.222222222222222 up to 2.25, thank you

Comment: @Rio Eduardo, so are you saying "always round up to 0.05"?

Comment: yes :) but not to 2.6666666 and etc only range 2.111111 until 2.444444

Comment: @Rio Eduardo, I've put another formula in for always round up. If this should only work for certain numeric ranges, then that's best done using if statements.

Answer (score 10):

you have 3 possibility : round(), floor(), ceil()

for you :

```
$step = 2; // number of step 3th digit
$nbr = round(2.333333333 * $step, 1) / $step; // 2.35

$step = 4; // number of step on 3th digit
$nbr = round(2.333333333 * $step, 1) / $step; // 2.325
```

[round](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php)

```
<?php
echo round(3.4);         // 3
echo round(3.5);         // 4
echo round(3.6);         // 4
echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
    echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

[floor](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.floor.php)

```
<?php
echo floor(4.3);   // 4
echo floor(9.999); // 9
echo floor(-3.14); // -4
?>
```

[ceil](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ceil.php)

```
<?php
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementary functions to round up / down to arbitrary number of decimals:

```
/**
* Round up to specified number of decimal places
* @param float $float The number to round up
* @param int $dec How many decimals
*/
function roundup($float, $dec = 2){
    if ($dec == 0) {
        if ($float < 0) {
            return floor($float);
        } else {
            return ceil($float);
        }
    } else {
        $d = pow(10, $dec);
        if ($float < 0) {
            return floor($float * $d) / $d;
        } else {
            return ceil($float * $d) / $d;
        }
    }
}

/**
* Round down to specified number of decimal places
* @param float $float The number to round down
* @param int $dec How many decimals
*/
function rounddown($float, $dec = 2){
    if ($dec == 0) {
        if ($float < 0) {
            return ceil($float);
        } else {
            return floor($float);
        }
    } else {
        $d = pow(10, $dec);
        if ($float < 0) {
            return ceil($float * $d) / $d;
        } else {
            return floor($float * $d) / $d;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$value = 2.3333333333;
echo number_format($value, 2);
```

Comment: still the same result -> 2.33

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code:

```
$value = 2.3333333333;
$value = round ( $value, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

best document is in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)