# roundup number after decimal to greatest value

Tags: php, math

issue with converting number of product to dozen.

I have 40 products and I want to convert it into dozen.

when I use this calculation `40 / 12 = 3.3333333333333335` and `number_format` to 1 decimal it returns `3.3` but it means `39` products

so I want that if number after decimal are more than 2 i.e `3.33333` then it round to greater number after decimal that is `3.4`

How can I convert that?

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564365/how-to-round-up-value-in-php

Comment: Are you looking to always round up? If so: `echo ceil(4.3);    // 5`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make sure a float will always be rounded up with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093608/how-can-i-make-sure-a-float-will-always-be-rounded-up-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can custom function round_up like:

```
function round_up($number, $precision = 2)
{
    $fig = pow(10, $precision);
    return (ceil($number * $fig) / $fig);
}

var_dump(round_up(3.3333333, 2));
```